# Offline and Online Functionality in Angular 2/4

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, angular2-services

I have to implement a Offline and Online functionality on the click of the button.

1. When user clicks button A, the whole application should go to offline mode (i.e. the pages needs to cached & any new entries in the form will be stored in browser's memory)
2. When user clicks button B, the stored data need to be pushed to the DB.

Please help me how can I achieve this functionality.

Comment: This is too broad. There's many factor that requires internet access. For example, Firebase DB SDK has the corresponding methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DIY version:

First, you need to put a switch in your service. If it is under local mode, cache or store all data on client side. It'd better to have a flag in data for judging if data has been synced to server or not. If it is under server mode, do whatever it is needed to push all data to server side.

Second, you will need a monitor service in background or when server mode is enabled, syncing action will be kicked once. The action or background process will check any not synced data and push them to server. When it is done, flag it as synced.

That is the general idea.

Code of my idea to achieve this. Create a parent service class:

```
class BaseService {
    protected execute(online: any, offline: any){
        if (this.config.mode == 'online')
            online();
        else
            offline();
    }
}
```

In actual child service

```
... extends BaseService {
    saveEmployee() {
        this.execute(() => {
            // do online stuff
        }, () => {
            // do offline stuff
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: How should I implement the switch in the service? I was thinking to have a separate service file for implementing and handling my offline data.

Comment: You can create a class with the switch as a public property and inject it to all services. Since injection will practice singleton, the property value will be shared within all services.

Comment: if i have two services online.service.ts and  offline.service.ts and both have the switch class injected. My application status was online and online.service.ts was serving my components, and when the user clicked offline then the component should be served from the offline.service.ts . How do you think I can make that switch on the runtime.

Comment: I am uncertain if that is a good approach. You component will need to identify which service to use. Why not just isolate it from component and let service layer do the magic, right? Component really does not care about if it is offline or online mode, its job is just manipulating data and view (like controller).

Comment: I agree with you! Just that I am thinking how can I achieve it in my code. Something init() within the service which could redirect to the online service file to offline service file, as I dont want to do if(online).. else... in the same file.